# Which sentence is the correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

You cannot envision ascension **with** your English skill set.

You cannot envision ascension **in** your English skill set.

Which is the correct one? I feel both are correct, and there is just a difference in meaning.

Comment: Since I can't imagine a native English speaker using the word _ascension_ like that, and can only guess what it might be intended to mean, it's very hard to answer your question. What meaning do you intend?

Comment: @Colin Fine I mean "growth in someone's English skill set".

Comment: They're both incorrect. Colin has given the reason. And even 'You cannot imagine improving aspects of your English skill set', while not ungrammatical, sounds a very odd thing to say.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Reason?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Colin hasn't given the reason.

Comment: Colin's reason was that you had used an inappropriate word. If you are learning English (or any subject), why would you not be able to imagine improving in it?

Comment: @Kate Bunting But that is metaphorical.

Comment: 'Ascension in your English skill set' and 'ascension with your English skill set' show no hits on Google, confirming my opinion that they are _totally_ unidiomatic (ie no person with reasonable competence in the English language would consider using the word 'ascension' to mean 'the making of an improvement'; 'ascension' is rarely used other than with people being say crowned king, or rather tongue-in-cheek for **great** achievements. So, as an ex-teacher, I'd mark _both_ sentences _wrong_. Try " 3 + 6 = 10 or 3 x 3 = 10. Which one is right?"  Answer: _They're both wrong._

Comment: The question of what preposition is standardly used with a certain phrase is unanswerable when the phrase itself has no standard use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will take the word *Ascension* to mean *Improvement*.

"You cannot envision ascension *with* your English skill set."

This would make it seem that you are carrying your "English" along with you as you ascend. Ascend *to what* is the question. The better word would be *Within*. Then the ascension-improvement would be of your English skills.

"You cannot envision ascension *in* your English skill set." The same applies here as well. They both make sense to you since you already have the meaning in mind. Within combines the two; with-in, "You cannot envision ascension *within* your English skill set."  This usage of *Within* is what will make sense to an English language listener.

Comment: << "You cannot envision ascension in your English skill set." ... This is what will make sense to an English language listener. >> You're encouraging bad practice. The sentence is unacceptable; you'd be laughed at for coming out with it.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth No, it's absolutely fine. Poetic language is brimming with such usages that, when taken literally, mean different things, but actually refer to something else that is made explicit by the context. Modern idiomatic expressions like "screwing up", "nailing something" and "holding one's horses" pertain to meanings oppugnant, to the author's intention, in a literal sense. However, such usages inoculate an element of creativity in the prose that draws the reader and the author closer. That's why most of their usage is overlooked by the conservative, formal, linguistics community.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I also used the word "inoculate" which somewhat means to "treat with or inject a vaccine" :-). I don't know about the US, but in India, it's perfectly fine. Whatever I have said might instigate a grammatical strife, ending in an impasse.

Comment: @Cognoscenti ELU deals with standard usages, not fanciful contrived wannabe  metaphors. And using poetic language with 'English skill set', as prosaic as it gets, is a register clash to end all register clashes. _They're both unidiomatic to the point of being unacceptable. Incorrect._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth You are correct (not unusual) and I have made the correction to add the final combination to the answer. I did not expect the second example, *in*, to make sense to the ELU. Thanks to Cognoscenti for pitching in as well.